# Graphviz - Correct embedding of planar graphs

Tags: graphviz

I have a .gv file with large graph (250+ nodes). It is planar. Yet I can not find a way to correctly embed it. Every algorithm gives a lot of intersections, while clearly there should be none.

Is it even possible to solve this task using GraphViz software?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible without manual manipulation, and as the graph size grows as you might expect, this becomes tedious.  [This post on the GraphViz forum](http://www.graphviz.org/content/how-avoid-crossing-planar-graph-dot-2380-macports) suggests that the planarity feature was never implemented:

> no code in released version counts flat edge crossings
>   Submitted by north on Fri, 10/02/2015 - 06:45.
>   We're really sorry, but don't see an obvious way to overcome this glitch.  Someone suggested a kickstarter project to support and extended Graphviz, for example to incorporate some published algorithm (or find a simple heuristic) to avoid flat edge crossings.

Sorry I don't have a more positive answer for you but I think it's "no."  At least maybe this will save you some time searching...

Comment: Thank you - this is what I expected. Your answer did indeed save a lot of time, though.