# How to prevent edge lapping in graphviz with circo layout

Tags: graphviz, overlap, edges

I was trying to draw a circular graph using GraphViz, and decided it would be the best to use `circo` for this graph.

Having taken advice in a post from 7 years ago, [How to prevent edges in graphviz to overlap each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967600/how-to-prevent-edges-in-graphviz-to-overlap-each-other), and using global `overlap=false` and `splines=true`, the edges still overlap with each other.

The whole graph can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWYY7.jpg), and is defined as:

```
digraph question6 {

 layout="circo"
 overlap=false
 splines=true
 node [shape="circle"]

 G1 [label="1, G"]
 G2 [label="2, G"]
 D11 [label="1, D1"]
 D12 [label="2, D1"]
 D21 [label="1, D2"]
 D22 [label="2, D2"]

 G1 -> D12 [label="c"]
 G1 -> G2 [label="a"]
 G2 -> D12 [label="a"]
 D11 -> G1 [label="d"]
 D11 -> D21 [label="e"]
 D11 -> D12  [label="c"]
 D12 -> G2 [label="d"]
 D12 -> D22 [label="c"]
 D21 -> G1 [label="d"]
 D21 -> D22 [label="c"]

 D22 -> D21 [label="b"]
 D22 -> G2 [label="d"]
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  "Edge overlap" almost always means wanting **planarity** and GraphViz simply has no setting to guarantee planarity.  See [my other answer on this topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45800371/graphviz-correct-embedding-of-planar-graphs)

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Really appreciate the intels! I now recall that planarity was a great part when I was learning discrete mathematics. Now that since graphviz won’t solve this out automatically, can I set it manually, or should I upgrade to diagram apps such as OmniFraffle and Visio? Thanks!

Comment: I can't speak for the feature set of those other packages.  I know quite a bit about GraphViz and dot but cannot comment on the others.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## As for now, there is not a viable way for this.

> One of the very difficult things that GraphViz is not yet able to
>   resolve is to determine if the graph is *planar*.